# How do I get the second element which matches a wildcard css selector?

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have a page with two buttons share the similar id in the pattern of button A id be "ABCNN_xxx" and button B id be "ABC(NN+1)_xxx" which NN is a number that being different on other pages with the same logic. My script needs to get those button universally on different pages so I use a wildcard css selector. However, since the two buttons share the same pattern, the wildcard selector would catch only the first button (A, with smaller NN number) it sees but cannot locate the second one.

I tried to put [2] behind the selector but seems it doesn't work like that. I am using the below css selector. It will get me the first match but not the remaining match.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[id^='ABC'][id$='_xxx']")).click();
```

Besides getting me ABC36_xxx for the first time, I would like to have ABC37_xxx for the second call instead of returning the first result. How should I achieve my objective?

Comment: Have you tried using find element by xpath? You can copy the xpath from browser (open webpage in a browser -> inspect element->point to the second button->right click and say copy xpath).

Comment: But I need to use a wildcard as the ids of the needed element are different on other pages. xpath would be too specific to a static id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you sure with the locator : `By.cssSelector("img[id^='ABC'][id$='_xxx']")` and it more than one, then collect them by :

```
List<WebElement> elmnts = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img[id^='ABC'][id$='_xxx']"));
```

And this to get second element :

```
elmnts.get(1).click();
```

Import this :

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
```

Comment: Great simple answer! I spent time trying to get the selector for the second matching element when it was much easier to FindElements() and pick the second in the list.

Answer (score 1):

you could select all into an array and loop over them using findElement**s**:
`driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img[id^='ABC'][id$='_xxx']")).click();`
Or you could add a flag class after clicking it:

- after the click add a "seleniumClicked" class to the button
- then change your selector to `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("img[id^='ABC'][id$='_xxx']:not(.seleniumClicked)")).click();`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java but I would love to learn how should I do so. Do you mind share some codes? Thank you so much.